# How to solve "client is public" Error in Microsoft Login Using Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, azure, firebase-authentication

I am having a issue with Firebase Microsoft login. I followed all the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth?hl=en&authuser=0) in Firebase's website and set everything in the Microsoft part. However, I am still encountering "Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented." error. I am using XCode 14.3.1 and Swift 5.8.1. Can anyone help me to solve this error? Here is my login function:

```
var provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
provider.customParameters = [
    "prompt": "consent",
    "tenant": "MY_TENANT_ID"
]
provider.scopes = []
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
  if error != nil {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unsuccessful Log In Attempt!", message: "Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
    if credential != nil {
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unsuccessful Log In Attempt!", message: "Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("*********ERROR************")
                print(error)
                print("*********ERROR************")
                
            } else {
                guard let authResult = authResult else {
                    return
                }
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error description:
"Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.
Trace ID: ...
Correlation ID: ...
Timestamp: 2023-08-08 09:01:15Z&timestamp=2023-08-08 09:01:15Zb"

I was not using my tenant id and just giving "organizations" as parameter. I changed that to private tenantID, but it did not change anything. Also, I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665783/firebase-microsoft-login-cannot-get-access-token-in-swift-ios) solution. Because it is outdated, it did not work either.

Comment: I will check it and get back to you. Are we talking about this part?: https://ibb.co/64Gcs0w

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. From the Azure AD portal, the administrator should authorize an access token (from "Implicit grant and hybrid flows").